# what is the passive voice form of the question?

Tags: active-voice

1 John likes  drinking water.

this is what i tried "drinking water has been liked by john".
 what is the passive voice form of the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The question is hard to decipher because what you give in #1 is **NOT** a question. So are you supposed to turn an indicative sentence in the active voice and simple present tense into a question in the same tense but passive voice? Or are you supposed to turn an indicative sentence in the active voice and simple present tense into an indicative sentence in the present voice and simple present tense? The correct answer depends on the actual question, which is unclear.

> Drinking water is liked by John

or

Is drinking water liked by John?

In any case, why did you switch from simple present into present perfect?